# uniqid versus mt_rand PHP function

Tags: php, performance, function, random

I want to know what is the best.
Performance, speed, and with the best results unique

Comment: Performance / Speed: Have you tested it?

Comment: why do you need a unique result? if you are creating a record id in a database, an auto increment column will be best and always unique.

Answer (score 2):

Just time it yourself to see performance / speed:

```
define( 'NUM_TESTS', 1000000);

$start = microtime( true);

for( $i = 0; $i < NUM_TESTS; $i++)
{
    mt_rand();
}

$end = microtime(true) - $start;
echo 'mt_rand: ' . $end . "\n";

$start = microtime( true);

for( $i = 0; $i < NUM_TESTS; $i++)
{
    uniqid();
}

$end = microtime(true) - $start;
echo 'uniqid: ' . $end . "\n";
```

As far as uniqueness, `mt_rand` returns a number while `uniqid` returns a random string, which has potentially far more combinations than `mt_rand`. In addition, `uniqid` has an additional parameter:

```
string uniqid ([ string $prefix = "" [, bool $more_entropy = false ]] )
```

Setting $more_entropy = true:

> should make the results more unique.

According to [the docs](http://us.php.net/uniq_id).

Answer (score 2):

uniqueid('', true) is simply a timestamp in hexadecimal form, so as long as you don't generate two in the same microsecond, they are always going to be different. keep in mind that it is for some reason faster with more entropy set to true and this includes microsecond so it has a greater chance of being truly unique. the problem with it is that it can be easier guessed than an mt_rand() value since it is based on the current time, so you would not want to use it in places where security relies on the unique value.

mt_rand() I would guess is slower since it generates a random value, although I have not put this to the test. the advantage is it would be more difficult to guess what someone elses random value is, so you could feasibly use it in situations where security rely on it. this will most likely also need to be tested against current values to make sure there is not an existing duplicate. the chances are extremely slim like winning the lottery, but it isn't outside of the realm of possibility.